# git branch --track vs -u difference

Tags: git, git-branch

I have a local branch which I want to link to a remote branch. So when I do `git pull` it will auto use linked remote branch

I tried to use `git branch --track origin/branchname`
but it did a weird thing and created kind of a tag with name origin/branchname
And `git pull` still didn't auto select linked branch

on other hand `git branch -u origin/branchname` did work and `git pull` autoselects correct branch

what is the diff with `--track` and `-u` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `git branch` command does (in my opinion, anyway) too many different things.

In particular, you can ask it to *create* a branch—a new branch name, that is; see [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)—with various settings for that new name.

You can also ask it to *modify* an *existing* branch, which is what you wanted to do.  The `-u` or `--set-upstream-to` option does this.

The `--track` option is for creating a new branch:

> I tried to use `git branch --track origin/branchname`but it did a weird thing and created kind of a tag with name `origin/branchname`

More specifically, it created a *local* branch named `origin/branchname`.  Normally any time you see `origin/foo`, `origin/master`, `origin/whatever`, these are *remote-tracking branches* (see the linked question).  Creating a *local* branch with such a name just sets things up to be confusing.  (*Git* won't have any trouble with it, it's just confusing for humans. :-) )